# Regex: how to extract incomplete date and convert

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, regex, regex-group

How can I get a date that may not contain the month or the day?

Right now I only know how to break the date

```
date_n= '2022-12'
match_year = re.search(r'(?P<year_only>(?P<year>\d+))', date_n)
match_month = re.search(r'(?P<whole_date>(?P<year>\d+)-(?P<month>\d+))', date_n)
match_day = re.search(r'(?P<whole_date>(?P<year>\d+)-(?P<month>\d+)-(?P<day>\d+))', date_n)

year = match_year.group('year_only')
month = match_month.group('month')
day = match_day.group('day')
```

Try and Except does not work.

Comment: You can make the day part optional like `\b(?P<whole_date>(?P<year>\d+)-(?P<month>\d+)(?:-(?P<day>\d+))?)\b` https://regex101.com/r/DPRGCh/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should build patterns for each `year`, `month` and `day` and match them all in one expression (making `month` and `day` optional):

```
import re

date_n= '2022-12'
year_pattern = r"(?P<year>\d{4})"
month_pattern = r"(?:-(?P<month>\d{1,2}))"
day_pattern = r"(?:-(?P<day>\d{1,2}))"
match_date = re.search(rf'{year_pattern}(?:{month_pattern}{day_pattern}?)?', date_n)

year = match_date.group('year')
month = match_date.group('month')
day = match_date.group('day')
```

Comment: It works but ... I don't know why I can't write the incomplete date to models.py in datefield 2022.12.

Comment: I can't possibly answer that without any details (what is models.py? how is datefield defined?). Try creating a new question if you're stuck with this other problem.

Comment: models.py is a file in Django. There I have a variable that only takes the full date. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#datefield